# WordPress PHP error getting posts from another wordpress blog

Tags: plugins, php, rest-api, json, feed

I'm using this code in the template-blog.php page of my website, to get posts from my first WP blog to the second WP blog, different websites using the same blog posts.

this code has been working great for years, but suddenly it stopped working giving me invalid argument foreach on line 133

```
 <?php
    /*
    Template Name: Blog
    */

    get_header(); ?>

    <?php
    /* $url = 'https://www.firstwp.com/wp-json/posts/';
    $response = wp_safe_remote_get( $url );
    if ( ! is_wp_error( $response ) ) {
        $remote_post = json_decode( wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response ) );
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($remote_post[0]);
         echo "</pre>";
    } */
    ?>

        <div class="main-body">
    <?php
    /*                      $get_car= "https://www.firstwp.com/wp-json/posts";
                        $cars_json = file_get_contents($get_car);
                        $cars_array = json_decode($cars_json, true);
                        echo "<pre>";
                        print_r($cars_array);
                         echo "</pre>";


                         $response = wp_remote_get( $get_car );
                        $rows = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response ) ;
                        $decode = json_decode(stripslashes($rows), true);
                        print_r($decode); */

                        // echo do_shortcode('[wpapi-posts s="WP-API" url="https://www.firstwp.com/wp-json/posts" posts_per_page="5"]');


    ?>



                            <?php
                            $args = array(
                                            'post_type' => 'post',
                                            'posts_per_page' =>0
                                        );
                                        query_posts( $args );
                            ?>

                    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                        <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
                            <header class="entry-header">
                                <?php if ( is_sticky() ) : ?>
                                    <hgroup>
                                        <h2 class="entry-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'twentyeleven' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                                        <h3 class="entry-format"><?php _e( 'Featured', 'twentyeleven' ); ?></h3>
                                    </hgroup>
                                <?php else : ?>
                                <h1 class="entry-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'twentyeleven' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
                                <?php endif; ?>

                                <?php if ( 'post' == get_post_type() ) : ?>
                                <!-- <div class="entry-meta">
                                    <?php //twentyeleven_posted_on(); ?>
                                </div> --> <!-- .entry-meta -->
                                <?php endif; ?>

                                <?php if ( comments_open() && ! post_password_required() ) : ?>
                                <div class="comments-link">
                                    <?php comments_popup_link( '<span class="leave-reply">' . __( 'Reply', 'twentyeleven' ) . '</span>', _x( '1', 'comments number', 'twentyeleven' ), _x( '%', 'comments number', 'twentyeleven' ) ); ?>
                                </div>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            </header><!-- .entry-header -->

                            <?php if ( is_search() ) : // Only display Excerpts for Search ?>
                            <div class="entry-summary">
                                <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                            </div><!-- .entry-summary -->
                            <?php else : ?>
                            <div class="entry-content">
                            <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                              the_post_thumbnail();
                            }?>
                               <?php the_excerpt( 200 ); ?>

                               <p class="but"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><img alt="" border="0" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/more.jpg"></a></p>
                            </div><!-- .entry-content -->
                            <?php endif; ?>


                                <?php $show_sep = false; ?>
                                <?php if ( 'post' == get_post_type() ) : // Hide category and tag text for pages on Search ?>
                                <?php
                                    /* translators: used between list items, there is a space after the comma */
                                    $categories_list = get_the_category_list( __( ', ', 'twentyeleven' ) );
                                    if ( $categories_list ):
                                ?>
                                <span class="cat-links">
                                    <?php printf( __( '<span class="%1$s">Posted in</span> %2$s', 'twentyeleven' ), 'entry-utility-prep entry-utility-prep-cat-links', $categories_list );
                                    $show_sep = true; ?>
                                </span>
                                <?php endif; // End if categories ?>

                                <?php endif; // End if 'post' == get_post_type() ?>

                                <?php if ( comments_open() ) : ?>
                                <?php if ( $show_sep ) : ?>
                                <span class="sep"> | </span>
                                <?php endif; // End if $show_sep ?>
                                <span class="comments-link"><?php comments_popup_link( '<span class="leave-reply">' . __( 'Leave a reply', 'twentyeleven' ) . '</span>', __( '<b>1</b> Reply', 'twentyeleven' ), __( '<b>%</b> Replies', 'twentyeleven' ) ); ?></span>
                                <?php endif; // End if comments_open() ?>

        </article><!-- #post-<?php the_ID(); ?> -->

                    <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>      


    <?php
   // $url = 'https://www.firstwp.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/';
   $url = 'https://www.firstwp.com/wp-json/posts/';
    $response = wp_safe_remote_get( $url );
    if ( ! is_wp_error( $response ) ) {
        $remote_post = json_decode( wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response ) );
        //echo "<pre>";
        //print_r($remote_post[0]);
        //echo "</pre>";
                        //echo '<h3><a href="' . esc_url( $remote_post[0]->link ) . '">' . esc_html( $remote_post[0]->title ) . '</a></h3>';

                        //remote post's content
                        //echo '<p>' . wp_kses_post( $remote_post[0]->content ) . '</p>';

    ?>

    <?php foreach( $remote_post as $remote_single_post){ ?>
    <article id="post-1" class="post-1 post type-post status-publish format-standard hentry category-uncategorized">
                            <header class="entry-header">
                                                            <h1 class="entry-title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( $remote_single_post->link ); ?>" title="Permalink to Hello world!" rel="bookmark" target="_blank"><?php echo esc_html( $remote_single_post->title ); ?></a></h1>

                                                        </header><!-- .entry-header -->

                                                    <div class="entry-content">
                                                    <div  class="api_content"><?php echo '<p>' . wp_kses_post( $remote_single_post->content ) . '</p>'; ?> </div>


                               <p class="but"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( $remote_single_post->link ); ?>" target="_blank"><img alt="" border="0" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/more.jpg"></a></p>
                            </div><!-- .entry-content -->


                                                                                                                    <span class="cat-links">
                                    <span class="entry-utility-prep entry-utility-prep-cat-links" style="color: #ff99CC;">Posted in</span>
                              <?php foreach( $remote_single_post->terms->category as $api_category){ ?>
                              <a href="<?php echo esc_html ($api_category->link)?>" rel="category tag" target="_blank"><?php echo esc_html ($api_category->name)?></a>, <?php } ?>                  
                                </span>



    </article>  
    <?php 

    ?>

    <?php } // end foreach ?>                       
    <?php
    }
    ?>
            <nav id="nav-below">

                <h3 class="assistive-text">Post navigation</h3>

                <div class="nav-previous"><a href="https://www.firstwp.com/blog/page/2/" target="_blank"><span class="meta-nav">←</span> Older posts</a></div>

                <div class="nav-next"></div>

            </nav>
    <script>
    $(document).ready( function (){
        $('.api_content').each( function(){
            $(this).find( "p, h1 ,ol , ul, h2" ).not("p:lt(3)").remove();
        });

        //alert(apiImage);
        //$( ".api_content" ).find( "p" ).empty();;

    });
        //$( ".api_content" ).contents().find( "img" ).css( "border", "10px solid #000;" );
    </script>




        </div>
    </div>

    <?php get_template_part('sidebar','home'); ?>

        <div class="clear"></div>
    </section>




    <?php
    //get_sidebar();
    get_footer();
```

it gives an error on this part

```
    <?php
   // $url = 'https://www.firstwp.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/';
    $url = 'https://www.firstwp.com/wp-json/posts/';
    $response = wp_safe_remote_get( $url );
    if ( ! is_wp_error( $response ) ) {
        $remote_post = json_decode( wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response ) );
        //echo "<pre>";
        //print_r($remote_post[0]);
        //echo "</pre>";
                        //echo '<h3><a href="' . esc_url( $remote_post[0]->link ) . '">' . esc_html( $remote_post[0]->title ) . '</a></h3>';

                        //remote post's content
                        //echo '<p>' . wp_kses_post( $remote_post[0]->content ) . '</p>';

    ?>

    <?php foreach( $remote_post as $remote_single_post){ ?>
    <article id="post-1" class="post-1 post type-post status-publish format-standard hentry category-uncategorized">
                            <header class="entry-header">
                                                            <h1 class="entry-title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( $remote_single_post->link ); ?>" title="Permalink to Hello world!" rel="bookmark" target="_blank"><?php echo esc_html( $remote_single_post->title ); ?></a></h1>

                                                        </header><!-- .entry-header -->

                                                    <div class="entry-content">
                                                    <div  class="api_content"><?php echo '<p>' . wp_kses_post( $remote_single_post->content ) . '</p>'; ?> </div>


                               <p class="but"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( $remote_single_post->link ); ?>" target="_blank"><img alt="" border="0" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/more.jpg"></a></p>
                            </div><!-- .entry-content -->


                                                                                                                    <span class="cat-links">
                                    <span class="entry-utility-prep entry-utility-prep-cat-links" style="color: #ff99CC;">Posted in</span>
                              <?php foreach( $remote_single_post->terms->category as $api_category){ ?>
                              <a href="<?php echo esc_html ($api_category->link)?>" rel="category tag" target="_blank"><?php echo esc_html ($api_category->name)?></a>, <?php } ?>                  
                                </span>



    </article>  
    <?php 

    ?>

    <?php } // end foreach ?>                       
    <?php
    }
    ?>
```

I'm not sure what is causing the problem is it has been working fine for years now, so any help would be appreciated
The idea is, I have 2 websites with different content, and I want the blog page to show the same content that I post in the FIRSTWP and show it on SecondWP

I've tried FeedWordPress plugin but it doesn't show the image in the posts page excerpt

Comment: Have you looked at `$remote_post` to see what it contains? 
It would seem it's not an array, as `foreach` expects.

Comment: well when I go to the commented out url, it gives me the posts of the blog, but the enable url string gives me "code: "rest_no_route",
message: "No route was found matching the URL and request method" but still when I switch the urls, it gives me catchable fatal warning STDClass error